# Nginx: how to let rewrite rules ignore files or folders

Tags: html, nginx

I use Nginx to serve a SPA (Single Page Application), in order to support HTML5 History API I have to rewrite all deeper routes back to the `/index.html`, so I follow [this article](http://readystate4.com/2012/05/17/nginx-and-apache-rewrite-to-support-html5-pushstate/) and it works! This is what I put in nginx.conf now:

```
server {
    listen 80 default;
    server_name my.domain.com;
    root /path/to/app/root;

    rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.html last;
}
```

However there's one problem, I have an `/assets` directory under the root contains all the css, js, images, fonts stuffs, I don't want to rewrite these urls, I just want to ignore these assets, how am I suppose to do?

Comment: Use different `location`s

Comment: @AlexeyTen I tried, but what I don't understand is if I use a dedicate location for `/assets`, what directive(s) should I put in this location block?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Put `rewrite` into one `location` and use other `location`s for assests/dynamic urls/etc.

```
server {
    listen 80 default;
    server_name my.domain.com;
    root /path/to/app/root;

    location / {
        rewrite ^ /index.html break;
    }

    location /assets/ {
        # Do nothing. nginx will serve files as usual.
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, I really don't know "do nothing" will do the magic!

I also try a more complex regex `rewrite ^/(?!assets|index.html) / last;`, this works as well, but I like your solution because it's clean and easy to understand.

Thank you!

Comment: @AaA, still works. Ask new question and show full config.